# cd commands not working from .bash_profile on MobaXTerm

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm on Windows 10, using MobaXterm. I have a persistent home directory, and I've created .bash_profile there. My .bash_profile contains:

`echo "Loading bash profile."
cd "/drives"`

When I open a new MobaXterm tab, I get:

`Loading bash profile
: No such file or directory`

But when I run:

`cd "/drives"`

from the command line, it changes directory to /drives.

I don't really need to go to /drives when a tab starts up, what I want to do is create alias for cd commands that go to long directory names without having to type them out every time, but no cd commands will work from .bash_profile, I always get 'No such file or directory'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted MobaXTerm support, and their reply was to convert the .bash_profile to unix format with this command:

```
dos2unix /home/mobaxterm/.bash_profile
```

Now the cd commands work as expected.

Comment: Thanks - this answer ended an hour of frustration.